# Function for sum of integer sequence(Python)

Tags: python, sum, assert

I have the basics of a function to help output the sum of a list of integers with input that has to be greater than 0.

However, I am new to the while 'assert' part of Python and struggling to implement an 'assert' statement into the code.

```
def sum(list):
    sum = 0
    for x in list:
        sum = sum + x
    return sum
```

Comment: Why do you want to include an `assert` statement?

Comment: What do you mean by "input has to be greater than 0", if the input is a list? Also, `sum` is a builtin function, no need to re-implement it.

Comment: sorry I am new to this and trying to understand the use of assert statements. It is to make sure the conditions; integer or floating-point and > 0, are met. Hope that makes sense. If not I would be happy to know more about assertions.

Comment: @JP.Code if what you mean is a sum of non negative elements, then massiou's answer is the best way you can do.

Comment: But if you're wondering about asserts in general, they are syntactic sugar for `if __debug__ and not condition: raise AssertionError(message)`. Because they are disabled by the `-O` flag, they should not be used for any functionality, only in tests and as debugging safeguards.

Answer (score 3):

No need to use assert, you could use a pythonic way such as list comprehension:

```
def my_sum(lst):
    return sum(x for x in lst if x > 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

One more! Because why not.

```
def my_sum(lst):
    return sum(filter((0).__lt__, lst))
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to define the default method 'sum' it already exist in python.

```
>>> lst = [1,2,3,4,-5]
>>> sum([x for x in lst if x > 0])
10
```

edit : made a mistake by not reading the question